# Sencha2 proxy retrieves data but list does not show

Tags: json, list, proxy, sencha-touch-2

Well this is what is happening, i have a list that i working fine if i hardcode the data using the data property on the store but when i try to use the proxy is not showing anything... the proxy manages to send the data & receive data from the server but still the list refuses to show anything...

This is the view:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.myListView', { 
extend: 'Ext.List',
xtype: 'myListView',
requires: ['MyApp.store.myListStore'],
config: {
    title: 'American Companies',
    grouped: false,
    itemTpl: '{company} {contact}',
    store: 'myListStore',
    onItemDisclosure: true
}});
```

The model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.myListModel', {  
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
    fields: ['company', 'contact']
   }
});
```

The Store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.myListStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',


    requires: ['MyApp.model.myListModel', 'MyApp.proxy.myListProxy'],


    config: {
        model: 'MyApp.model.myListModel',
        proxy: 'searchProxy',
        autoLoad: true,
        grouper: {
            groupFn: function (record) {
                return record.get('contact').substr(0, 1);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The proxy:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.proxy.myListProxy', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    alias: 'proxy.searchProxy',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    callbackKey: 'callback',
    type: 'json',
    config: {
        model: 'MyApp.model.myListModel',
        url:  '/myUrl that works',   
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data' // E.g. {results: [{id: 123, description: 'some     text'}, {...}]},
        }
    },
    read: function (operation, callback, scope) {
           Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '/myUrl that works',   
            //success: passFn,   // function called on success
            failure: failFn,
            jsonData: {
                "data": {
                    "fields": ["company", "contact"],
                }
            }
        });

    },


    filterParam: undefined,


    /**
     * NOTE: so I can add other params as I needed the params for a search request
     * You could use extraParams instead
     */
    buildRequest: function(operation) {
        var request = this.callParent(arguments);
        var params  = request.getParams();
//        var searchRequest = getSearchRequest(); // helper method
//        if (searchRequest) {
//            Ext.apply(params, searchRequest);
//        }
        return request;
    }


});


function failFn(msg) {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Ajax Error', msg);
}
```

Comment: why do you want to override `read` method in proxy ?

Comment: Well truth be said it's the way it works for me... i couldn't do it without the read function, well without the ajax request in fact.. the proxy alone didn't send any data, i'm new at this haha

Comment: checkout answer below. I tried it myself and it worked. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `read` override to following -

```
read: function (operation, callback, scope) {
    var that = this;

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'yout_url_here',
        success: function(response,request){
            var receivedData = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText.trim());

            operation.setResultSet(Ext.create('Ext.data.ResultSet', {
                records: receivedData.data,
                total  : receivedData.data.length
            }));

            operation.setSuccessful();
            operation.setCompleted();

            if (typeof callback == "function") {
                callback.call(scope || that, operation);
            }
        },
        failure: failFn,
        jsonData: {
            "data": {
                "fields": ["company", "contact"]
            }
        }
    });

},
```

As per documentation of **read** method -

> Performs the given read operation. If you override this method in a custom Proxy, remember to always call the provided callback method when you are done with your operation.

So you need to call that callback again. But just calling it won't be sufficient. The data received from service need to be allotted to `Ext.data.Operation`. So a new `ResultSet` have to create and assign data to it. *This will allow store to assign data to list.* If `ResultSet` not set, store will not be loaded with data.

I tried this with following json and it worked -

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "company":"a",
         "contact":"b"
      },
      {
         "company":"a",
         "contact":"b"
      },
      {
         "company":"a",
         "contact":"b"
      },
      {
         "company":"a",
         "contact":"b"
      }
   ]
}
```

Give this a shot. But IMHO, you won't probably need to override `read` method. If you want to process received data before attaching it to list, then you might need this method. I don't know you want this or not.

But above solution worked for me and will for you too. :)

Comment: It works like a charm!! thanks a lot! However i'm still scratching my head with the reader issue, could you be so kind to enlight me about how would it be without the reader?

Comment: glad it helped you. if you just remove `read` overrride, it should work. You've given defaults in config for rootProperty and type of data. That's sufficient for proxy. i'll try to give details in spare time. :D

Comment: Thanks!! I would really like to refactor it and learn the right way of doing it, you've done a lot already, so thanks again!